# Should I make changes to my question regarding transmitting short audio streams via Bluetooth?

Tags: support, specific-question, reopen-closed

I would like to figure out why a question that I recently asked was closed. My understanding is that it is okay to ask questions about protocols and standards on Stack Overflow, as they are quite common and important to developers, but I guess that my question was closed because some people disagree with that (?) I don't know, maybe someone of you has a better explanation.

After the question was closed, the only change I made to it was to add:

> Edit: I'm not seeking recommendations for books, tools, software
>   libraries and the question can be answered with facts and citations.
>   Please reopen this question.

Because the close message said:

> We don’t allow questions seeking recommendations for books, tools,
>   software libraries, and more. Edit the question so it can be answered
>   with facts and citations. You can edit the question or post a new one.

If possible, I would really like to edit my original question text to fit Stack Overflow or maybe another Stack Exchange site, but I honestly don't understand what the problem is. Is my question just completely incompatible with Stack Overflow?

*[Transmit short audio streams from a smartwatch to Android with minimal power consumption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62050746/transmit-short-audio-streams-from-a-smartwatch-to-android-with-minimal-power-con)*

Comment: That edit isn't any good, nor is that comment. You can't notify close voters like that (or at all for that matter). Only dupe hammers/ gold badge holders can be @-mentioned when they dupe vote a question.

Comment: Without deep knowledge of the technologies involved in your question I would certainly agree that it is asking for recommendations. The question rather clearly states that you don't know what to use and you'd like to know what's best. Seems pretty clear that you are looking for suggestions to me.

Comment: While it's probably closed for the wrong reason it's a fairly broad questions because there's so many ways to go about it. For example one of the probably 20 ways I'd recommend is the custom Nordic BLE UART profile: https://github.com/ThingEngineer/ESP32_BLE_client_uart

Comment: this is clearly seeking for recommendation and finally also opion based.  Try one and if it doesn'zt work write a new question to explain what doesn't work and see if someone has a suggestion.

Comment: Meta information (information about the question itself) does not belong in the question. That is what comments are for (despite the word "commets").

Answer (score 3):

What is nice about your question is that you prepared the list upfront for us. So we can limit our recommendation to one of those and elaborate in the answer about our opinion why our recommendation is the best.

This is what I suggest you do:

- Pick any of those protocols.
- (Try to) Implement (a part of) it to the best of your abilities <sup>1</sup>.
- Share in the question what problem you have run into.
- Show the code that causes your headaches.
- Ask for a solution to that problem.
- Offer that you are not bound to the protocol you picked, list the alternatives you've considered.

Answers will fix the problem or offer an alternative implementation with a different protocol.

Or:

- Pick any of those protocols
- Explain that you've found to do X
- Explain you want to know how to do Y as that follows on X
- Offer that you are not bound to the protocol you picked, list the alternatives you've considered.

Keep in mind that X and Y need to be small features / steps in the grant scheme of the thing you're building.

Answers will explain how to do Y or advice you to pick a different protocol that can do X and Y. Worst case it is revealed it is not possible (yet) what you want.

---

<sup>1. or choose the one that you most likely expect to fail</sup>

Comment: I don't mean to complain, I realize you're supposed to put effort in your question, but implementing something like this could take weeks if not months and it would be kinda sad to potentially waste that time on the wrong approach, considering someone just could have been able to tell me that "Protocol X is completely unfit" or "The XYZ Standard has been created for this purpose." :/ ... or maybe even "What you're trying to achieve is currently not possible."

Comment: @Forivin well, if it is that difficult then see my second option.

Comment: What is the problem with recommendation questions anyway? If you can ask a question like yours, then it shows that the problem is not unfit for Stackoverflow. If you then ask and people tell you that it's impossible with your tool, they will recommend you a tool that does work and then this just seems silly.

Comment: @tobiornottobi The difference is that the question now describes a practical programming problem that can have a couple of answers, one of which might be a tool, a workaround, an yet unknown API. *Find me a tool is not a programming problem*. See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad among the many more on this same topic both here on MSO and on MSE. To cater for those that still can't resist or find it silly that you can't ask these questions we've created a whole site for Software Recs: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic